# Recursive function with stopping condition but without base case still works

Tags: c

I tried to solve the problem by calculating `sum` up to `n` without knowing about the base case and come up with this. It works but I don't know why.

```
int sumUpTo(int num)
{
    int i, sum = 0;      // I also tried not to initialize sum here but the results are the same
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        sum = sumUpTo(num - 1) + num;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sumUpTo(num));
    return 0;
}
```

I figured out that this function has the stopping condition `i=num` but no base case, the loop will stop with `sum = sumUpTo(0) + 1 + ... + num`. How could the program work without knowing the value of `sumUpTo(0)`?
What could possibly happen here?
Did the program assume the value of `sumUpTo(0)` is 0 (even with/without initialization of the variable `sum`)?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is just that - *undefined*. In your case, not initializing `sum` means that it's starting value could be anything ... including zero.

Comment: The value of `sumUpTo(0)` is "known" in that the loop does not run. That means `sum=0` needs to be initialized. Failing to initialize it results in nonsense (undefined behaviour) output.

Comment: *even with/without initialization of the variable sum*. That's Undefined Behaviour. With UB the result is unpredictable. It can get a garbage value, it can crash it can even appear to "work". But code with UB can fail at any time. [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Comment: Tip: Usually you use loops *or* recursion, not both. If you end up with both in your solution, check your algorithm carefully because you might be mixing up two valid approaches to the problem that do not work when combined.

Comment: Your loop repeatedly (for `num>1`) assigns to `sum`, throwing away every value but the last.

Comment: Your `for`-loop is unnecessary. As @DavisHerring says it either does not run or only stores the value of the last iteration. Hence the `for`-statement has an effect equivalent to `if(num>0) ...`. Therefore, you did implement the base case (`num <= 0`) where the recursion is not invoked.

Comment: By the way, 1+2+...+n = n*(n+1)/2.

Comment: @ErikBaghdasaryan I want to calculate 1+2+...+n. Thank you.

Comment: After reading the answer I believe it's Undefined Behaviour in the case I don't initialize sum. When I initialize it the loop doesn't start and so I set the base case of sumUpTo(0) = 0 without realizing it. Thanks!

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You didn't set base value of num variable, but it works successfully
  This is specific case of your code.
- In this code, you used 'for' statement
  If incoming num is 0, it doesn't pass via 'for' statement because 0 < 0 is not true. that's why it returns initial sum value with zero in last final loop
- Take this reference for safe algorithm, This is the standard code for recursive function

```
int sumUpTo(int num)
{
    if(num == 0)
      return 0;
    return sumUpTo(num - 1) + num;
}
```

Comment: In the standard code there's no loop, just a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you enter `3` as your input.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)   // Returns 3 + 3 = 6
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)   // Returns 2 + 1 = 3
        for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)   // Returns 1 + 0 = 1
            for(i = 0; i < 0; i++) // Returns 0
```

Here the recursion will end because that will not call another instance

If you don't initialize `sum`, as your comment says, the function can still work, only the result is undetermined.

Answer (score 0):

It works as in your for loop you have

```
for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

if `num` is a 0 or lower the for loop would never execute and since you have

```
int sum = 0;
```

it will return 0 as it never entered the for loop and everytime your function gets restarted(recalled) it will the current copy of `num` to 0..